Rendering chunks in parallel to the entry file
enter image description here
enter image description here
I want to solve the following problem in js:
When the page refreshes, I have 1 entry file pulled up in html and after it has loaded, its chunks are pulled up. I would like to bypass this structure a bit and not wait for app.js to load, but load the chunks I need in parallel. Is it possible to do this if these chunks are assets of my entry app.js?
